# XML is crazy. It is not showing real position of elements

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm having problems with a layout. I have this structure:

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinarLayout>
        <Button/>
        <RelativeLayout>
            <ImageButton/>
            <ImageButton/>
            <ImageButton/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinarLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I want the three ImageButtons centered and one next to the other like this:

```
IMG1   IMG2   IMG3
```

For this purpose, I've centered the elements inside the `RelativeLayout` using `android:gravity="center"` and I've used `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/element"` and `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/element"` to order the elements the way I want.

When I check the result on the `GraphicalLayout` option, it is showing exactly what I want (I've never had problems with this view, it **always** shows the elements as I write on the XML file) but then I compile and execute and it is all disordered. I've tried **a lot** of different ways to order the elements but it is doing what it want... This is the first time it happened to me in almost two years of development.

I've also closed Eclipse but nothing's changed.

**EDIT to add information**

I want the elements to be like this:

`IMG1   IMG2   IMG3`

In the GraphicalLayout it is all ok but in the emulator the three IMGS are overlapping.

Here's the complete code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bugbox_wall_port" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/writeNewMsg"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp" >
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/spyMsgs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/msgspy" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/playerMsgs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/msgplyr"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spyMsgs" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/allyMsgs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/msgally"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playerMsgs" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I do not know how to solve it. Is driving me nuts. What's the problem with this layout? Why the elements aren't ordered? How can I solve it and order the elements as I do always?

Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So what exactly is your question? I don't completely understand.

Comment: @0gravity edited with more info!

Comment: Do the 3 images have to be centered horizontal?

Comment: @0gravity Yes, they have to be centered horizontal.

Comment: Here's an image which will explain you graphically my problem: imageshack.us/photo/my-images/198/sinttulo2kv.jpg

Comment: Try to replace `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playerMsgs"` to `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/playerMsgs"` and in other places too.

Answer (score 0):

small idea:

how about using `android:src` instead of `android:background` ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/writeNewMsg"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp" >
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/spyMsgs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/icon"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/playerMsgs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
                android:background="@drawable/icon"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/spyMsgs" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/allyMsgs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/icon"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/playerMsgs" />
         </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your work, but it is not working... In my `GraphicalLayout` I see the layout **exactly** as you've posted here. But on emulator it is all disordered and overlapped...

Comment: I ran it on my phone and it looks the same way as the image I posted, probably the problem is somewhere else? Also how big are those 3 images? do you want to scroll horizontally?

Comment: Here's an image which will explain you graphically my problem: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/198/sinttulo2kv.jpg/

Comment: The layout that you posted is the whole layout? I just ran my code on emulator and it works. So probably you have something else on your layout that is causing a problem.

Comment: I removed the LinearLayouts. Here's the entire code: http://pastebin.com/reYE5RNQ

Comment: I ran your exact code on my emulator and this is what I get. http://s16.postimage.org/szegqguv9/Untitled.png

Comment: I do not understand it at all... Why does Android do this to me? lol

The first layout is a RL?

Comment: If it is a RelativeLayout, because it is the problematic layout.

Comment: lol yea I see what you are saying...well try changing that to a linear layout like the others.

Comment: I do not want LinarLayout. I want RelativeLayout because I want to use params that aren't available on LinearLayout like `align` so my idea is to change all Linear to Relative.

Comment: Why do you use `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playerMsgs"`? there is a `+` after `@` - it should not be there. It should be `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/playerMsgs"`, `+` - is a flag, telling that this id is new, but not one of olds. And in other places too

Comment: Yea you are right, that was from your code and did not see it. But yea it should not have the + sing.

Comment: I removed `+` but same negative result... I'm almost sure this is not the problem because in all the code of the app I've it with the `+` and it is working properly...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Last thing I would try is to clean the project and restart eclipse, sometimes that can do miracles. Also just to be safe make sure you use the + sign just to set up a new Id.