# RelativeLayout position problems

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a `layout` which contains 4 horizontal `LinearLayouts` with 3 `ImageButtons` inside each one.

Now I want to convert those `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout` because I need to add some more elements and I have to use `toRightOf`, `alignParentTop` etc.

Here's the code I'm using to do this change:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bugbox_wall_port" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/writeNewMsg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="New" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp" >
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/spyMsgs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/msgspy" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/playerMsgs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/msgplyr"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/spyMsgs" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/allyMsgs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/msgally"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/playerMsgs" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp" >
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/battleMsgs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/msgbatt" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/skynetMsgs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/msgnet" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/transportMsgs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/msgtrans" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp" >
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/expeditionMsgs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/msgexp" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/newsMsgs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/msgnews" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/buildingMsgs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/msgbuild" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp" >
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/allMsgs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/msgall" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/binMsgs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/msgbin" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

But I do not know why, the `RelativeLayout` is being problematic.

Here's an image where I explain graphically which's my problem:

http://img811.imageshack.us/img811/5479/stackes.jpg

It is driving me nuts. I do not know why is this happening. I've used RelativesLayout before and they weren't problematic.

So my question is: Why is this happening? and then How can I fix this error?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Didn't you posted the same question already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749552/xml-is-crazy-it-is-not-showing-real-position-of-elements/11749895#comment15617034_11749895

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I was setting an ID to the views programatically and I didn't realise...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. I commented out the linear layouts at the bottom. If the relative layout works the way you want it to then you can adjust the other linears accordingly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bugbox_wall_port" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/writeNewMsg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="New" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp" >
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/spyMsgs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/playerMsgs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/spyMsgs" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/allyMsgs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/playerMsgs" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <!-- <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp" >
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/battleMsgs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/msgbatt" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/skynetMsgs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/msgnet" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/transportMsgs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/msgtrans" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp" >
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/expeditionMsgs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/msgexp" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/newsMsgs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/msgnews" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/buildingMsgs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/msgbuild" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp" >
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/allMsgs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/msgall" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/binMsgs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/msgbin" />
        </LinearLayout> -->
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```